# Tensorboard not working due to import error

Tags: python, tensorboard

I have sucessfully logged to the output file in tensorboard but when I try and call it from the command line I get the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mpkan\anaconda3\envs\rlproject\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\mpkan\anaconda3\envs\rlproject\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\MPKan\Anaconda3\envs\RLProject\Scripts\tensorboard.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <mod
ule>
  File "c:\users\mpkan\anaconda3\envs\rlproject\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line 40, in <
module>
    from tensorboard import default
  File "c:\users\mpkan\anaconda3\envs\rlproject\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\default.py", line 38, i
n <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.audio import audio_plugin
  File "c:\users\mpkan\anaconda3\envs\rlproject\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\audio\audio_plu
gin.py", line 23, in <module>
    from werkzeug import wrappers
  File "c:\users\mpkan\anaconda3\envs\rlproject\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\__init__.py", line 151, in
 <module>
    __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
  File "c:\users\mpkan\anaconda3\envs\rlproject\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\exceptions.py", line 71, i
n <module>
    from werkzeug.wrappers import Response
  File "c:\users\mpkan\anaconda3\envs\rlproject\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers\__init__.py", lin
e 26, in <module>
    from .common_descriptors import CommonRequestDescriptorsMixin
  File "c:\users\mpkan\anaconda3\envs\rlproject\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers\common_descriptor
s.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..http import dump_csp_header
ImportError: cannot import name 'dump_csp_header' from 'werkzeug.http' (c:\users\mpkan\anaconda3\envs
\rlproject\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\http.py)
```

Does anybody know what the problem is here?

Comment: I am using PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and solved by uninstalling the tensorboard in the pip and installing using the [Tensorboard anaconda distribution](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorboard) within my own conda environment.

How is your tensorboard installed? Maybe you could try:

```
conda activate <your-env-name>
pip uninstall tensorboard
conda install -c conda-forge tensorboard
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error with Werkzeug 1.0.0
I resolve with Werkzeug downgrade

```
pip install Werkzeug==0.16.1
```